# How to make a link out of text on the fly? -- JQuery beginner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of these on a page:

```
<div class="item" id="555">
  <div class="wrapper>
    <p>Make Link One</p>
  </div>
  <p class="action">Make Link Two</p>
</div>
```

How can I dynamically make the 2 texts links based on the id 555? ie. They both should be links to `http://555`

There is a unique business requirement which is the reason they're not just normal  hrefs to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just bind a click event handler to the containing div that uses it's own ID to redirect the user:

```
$('.item').on('click', function () {
    window.location = 'http://' + this.id;
});
```

If you have other content inside the container element that should not trigger the redirect then you can bind to the `<p>` elements inside the container:

```
$('.item').on('click', 'p', function () {
    window.location = 'http://' + $(this).parents('.item:first')[0].id;
});
```

BTW, IDs should not start with numbers. Here's a link to the correct syntax for IDs: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7. In the first example replaces the depreciated `.bind()` and in the second example it replaces the depreciated `.delegate()`.

Comment: Is there a way to set styles on it upon hover so it looks like a normal link? (i.e. show cursor, underline, etc)

Comment: That can be done with some CSS. `.item p:hover {text-decoration: underline;}`. You *can* use JavaScript but **I'd recommend CSS**: `$('.item').find('p').on('mouseenter', function () {$(this).css({'text-decoration':'underline'})}).on('mouseleave', function () {$(this).css({'text-decoration':'none'});});`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var href = $this.parents('.item:first')[0].id;
    $this.wrap('<a href=http://"' + href + '">');
});
```

`.each` loops through the found `p` elements. It then looks for the parent iwth a class `.item` (`$this.parents('.item:first')`) to get the id. The `[0]` part turns the jQuery object into just a standard DOM element so that we can easily grab the `id` property from that element (you could also have done `$this.parents('.item:first').attr('id')` to stick with pure jQuery). Finally, we wrap the `p` in an anchor tag with the correct `href`.

Comment: If you use `.parents('.item:first')` you can support `<p>` tags at any level.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".item p").each(function(){
  var t1 = $(this).text();
  var linkid = $(this).parents('.item:first').attr("id");


  $(this).parent().append('<a href="http://' + linkid + '">' + t1 + '</a>');
  $(this).remove();

  });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, assuming that you’d like it to apply to every `p` which is a child of an element with the `item` class:

```
$(function(){
    $('.item p').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.contents().wrap($('<a>', { href: $this.closest('.item').attr('id') }));
    });
});
```